# How to see if a Reader is at EOF?

Tags: java, eof

My code needs to read in all of a file.  Currently I'm using the following code:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
while (r.ready()) {
  String s = r.readLine();
  // do something with s
}
r.close();
```

If the file is currently empty, though, then `s` is null, which is no good.  Is there any `Reader` that has an `atEOF()` method or equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard pattern for what you are trying to do is:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
String s = r.readLine();
while (s != null) {
    // do something with s
    s = r.readLine();
}
r.close();
```

Comment: The ready() method only tells whether the next read will block. If the Reader is at eof the next call will not block; it will return immediately with an EOF indication (null for readline, -1 for read).

Comment: Even better: do-while instead of while.

Comment: The JavaDoc of `BufferedReader.readLine()` says it returns "A String containing the contents of the line... or null **if the end of the stream has been reached**"

Comment: What would happen if my file contains `null` as string ??? I am unable to read full file, can this be a reason ?

Comment: @I-droid `"null"` and `null` are two pretty different things.

Comment: The 'old-school' pattern is `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`. Your way you have to test for null twice.

Comment: +EJP You mean I need to assign to `s` twice. Which I prefer, for clarity.

Comment: I mean you have to both assign and test `s` twice.

Comment: `(line = in.readLine()) != null` is overloaded with 2 meanings. And the number of assignments and tests is equal -- n+1.

Comment: Overloaded with what two meanings? And don't make personal remarks here. I don't. @Synesso.

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read()) say:

*`public int read() throws IOException`*
*Returns:
The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.*

So in the case of a Reader one should check against EOF like

```
// Reader r = ...;
int c;
while (-1 != (c=r.read()) {
    // use c
}
```

In the case of a BufferedReader and readLine(), it may be

```
String s;
while (null != (s=br.readLine())) {
    // use s
}
```

because readLine() returns null on EOF.

Comment: Wouldn't the character or line be unreachable after it's read? Unless the position is explicitly reset, this looks like throwing away bytes from the stream. (Especially if the user wants to check EOF without consuming further bytes)

Comment: @Kcits this is why a variable is declared in each case; prior to comparison, that variable is written to: while (-1 != ( **c=r.read()** )

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
public static boolean eof(Reader r) throws IOException {
    r.mark(1);
    int i = r.read();
    r.reset();
    return i < 0;
}
```

Comment: *If and only if* the `Reader` supports `mark()` and `reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

the ready() method will not work. You must read from the stream and check the return value to see if you are at EOF.

Comment: Well, it *will* work, in many cases, but it won't do what is required to answer this question.