# 5 line input produces 4 line output until I press enter once more

Tags: java

my code was supposed to output 5 cases but instead it outputs 4 only and I have to press enter once more for the 5th output to be printed
the code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BeautifulStrings2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //File f=new File("input.txt");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        //BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            String s=in.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(s);
            String chars="";
            if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))){
                chars+=s.charAt(0);
            }
            else {
                chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
            }
            for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
                boolean flag=true;
                for (int k=0;k<chars.length();k++){
                    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j))){
                        if (chars.charAt(k)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j))){
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag){
                    chars+=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j));
                }
            }
            String temp=chars;
            chars="";
            for (int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
                if (temp.charAt(j)>64&&temp.charAt(j)<91)
                    chars+=temp.charAt(j);
            }
            int [] numbers=new int[chars.length()];
            Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
            for (int j=0;j<chars.length();j++){
                for (int k=0;k<s.length();k++){
                    if (chars.charAt(j)==Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(k))){
                        numbers[j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(chars);
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            int factor=26,sum=0;
            for (int j=chars.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                sum+=numbers[j]*factor;
                factor--;
            }
            System.out.println("Case #"+i+": "+sum);
        }
    }

}
```

the expected output :

```
Case #1: 152
Case #2: 754
Case #3: 491
Case #4: 729
Case #5: 646
```

the actual output :

```
Case #1: 152
Case #2: 754
Case #3: 491 
Case #4: 729
```

and when I press enter one more time the fifth case is printed .. how can force it to be printed without having to change the input, which is

```
5
ABbCcc
Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!
Ignore punctuation, please :)
Sometimes test cases are hard to make up.
So I just go consult Professor Dalves
```

Comment: You need to tell your program that you've reached the end of the line when using standard input, thus pressing enter is required. However, having a new-line character at the end of a file is not required since you can check for end-of-file.

Comment: how can check for the end of the file ?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/274770//java/check-EOF-Java) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714090/how-to-see-if-a-reader-is-at-eof).

Comment: What is wrong?It works fine for me!