# How does BufferedReader.readLine() handle EOF or slow input?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Documentation says:

> `readLine()` Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Does that mean, that when there is something like `"hello"` on the input and nothing more, the `readLine()` will wait until the `\n` character comes, or is it capable of recognizin `EOF` or something?

What will the function return in situation where on the input appears `"Hello"` and after 5 seconds `" world!"`?

Comment: It looks like you're asking the wrong question. What are you trying to do? What are you reading and what protocol does that implement? What _do_ you want to happen when you read "Hello", then five seconds nothing, and then "world!"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does that mean, that when there is something like "hello" on the input and nothing more, the readLine() will wait until the \n character comes, or is it capable of recognizin EOF or something?

It will wait until either a line terminator or end of stream is received. If end of stream was received, it will return the partial line, and `null` next time.

> What will the function return in situation where on the input appears "Hello" and after 5 seconds " world!"?

1. If you're reading from a socket and you've set a read timeout shorter than five seconds it will throw `SocketTimeoutException`.
2. Otherwise if EOL or EOS appears along with " world!" or within the read timeout if set, it will return "Hello world!".
3. Otherwise it will block.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in documentation, even though somewhat implicit -

> public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException; Reads 
>   a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a
>   carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a
>   linefeed. Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, **not
>   including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
>   stream has been reached**

I think this hints you that it can recognise EOF by giving you null as a return value.

Here is another answer:

[How to see if a Reader is at EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714090/how-to-see-if-a-reader-is-at-eof)